# How to initialise or bind ListItems that are defined in App.config into a VB.Net wpf ComboBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, vml

I am designing a test-app that will be used in multiple stations in a flexible way so that the user can define the purpose of the use. Previously I have set this up using a txt .ini file (using VB 6 or Python) but following the suggestions of the VB.Net philosophy I am attempting to use the XML App.config file to work as the initialisation data-source. Following this approach I have been guided to use the machine-coding facilities of the App.config set-up table (by first entering a string into the value-field of the settings table, entering it and then erasing it). Thus I have a machine-written snippet of VML code which I attach below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

In accordance with my intention to populate the Combo-box with a list of strings which can be selected by the user to propagate an option-specific configuration I have selected: System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection as the variable type in the settings table for this app.

My difficulties are that I cannot find any definition of how to enter a list of strings into the App.config XML file. Furthermore I cannot see how to bind such a list of strings to a ListIndex in a WPF ComboBox. I can find examples of binding between controls on a page but none from the XML App.config file which I assume is handled by the Application Start-up event.

Any insight would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a completely different approach. Save your list as XML from a separate Utility . Then deserialize and bind to ComboBox.

```
Class MainWindow
    Private lst As New List(Of String)
Private Sub btnFillCombo_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnFillCombo.Click
    '1. Create an instance of XML Serializer
    Dim xs As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of String)))
    '2. Create a Stream for your file
    Using fs As Stream = New FileStream("MyList.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
        '3. Deserialize your Stream and cast to List(Of String)
        lst = CType(xs.Deserialize(fs), List(Of String))
    End Using
    cboList.ItemsSource = lst
End Sub


    Private Sub btnSaveList_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSaveList.Click
        ' FileStream(FileName, Mode, Access, Share) intellisense overload #9 out of 15
        Using fs As Stream = New FileStream("MyList.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Dim xs As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of String)))
            xs.Serialize(fs, lst)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLoadList_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnLoadList.Click
        lst.Add("Mathew")
        lst.Add("Mark")
        lst.Add("Luke")
        lst.Add("John")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The btnLoadList and the btnSaveList would be in a separate Utility only run once.

Comment: At first I was surprised to see that you propose to activate the deserialization with a button-click event. I investigated why you did not propose a main-window constructor to do this. I found that one could use a start-up handler in the application.xaml.vb code file. This is part of an implementation of a container which starts the main-window using a .Show() method after the dependencies have been populated. However the container class is part of the EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension: not part of the VS Community package! Shame: we have to press a button to initialise a VB.Net app!

Comment: This code could have been in a form load. I just put it in a button for my testing purposes.

Comment: I implemented as you suggested except that the deserialization is carried out in a constructor method in the MainWindow class. Works perfectly now. For the benefit of others wishing to make a sort of app initialisation file I followed Mary's suggestion. I built a config maker app that machine writes the XML file at first with a "hard-coded" list of strings. Then I altered this app read in the XML file so that the content can be edited to make an updated "corrected" config.xml file. Of course I deserialized the config.xml file in my main app which of course uses this file to initialize it.

Comment: I am so glad it worked and thanks for the extended architecture info. If my answer was helpful please accept it with the check mark to the left of the answer.